# Rollover child changes parent

Tags: html, css

Is there a way through pure CSS to change the style of a parent LI on the hover of a child LI?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    1
    <ul>
      <li>10</li>
      <li> 20</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

So that when I hover over 10 or 20, a style is applied to 1 or 2?

Comment: Just to be safe: you're not after something like this are you? http://jsfiddle.net/NKDzf/1/

Comment: Close but not quite. I don't want to affect the whole parent ul, I just want to be able to hover over the '10' li, and it will apply a style to the parent li - '1' in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the overall thing you're after (as I understand it) is just not possible with pure CSS. The closest you can get is http://jsfiddle.net/NKDzf/10/ or http://jsfiddle.net/NKDzf/12/

Comment: The only time you can really achieve this effect is if you do a `ul li:hover`. Hovering over any child elements will cause the parent li to go into hover state (assuming they are all contained within the same wrapper).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no parent selector in CSS.

See here for why this is the case:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

In short: performance reasons.